# Is there a longer straight road in Unova than Route 3?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Route 3 outside of the Pokémon Daycare has a long path you can travel in a straight line to hatch eggs quickly. It's a straight horizontal and there are no trainers or obstacles in the way. There are no doorways at either end that you might stumble into.

Is there a longer such road in Black/White or Black/White 2, or is Route 3 the longest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In B/W, I found Skyarrow Bridge to be the best place.

You can make a racing game out of it if you get bored. Starting on the Nacrene side of the bridge, go up the side, then edge forward until you can just see trucks going in and out, on the left of your screen. When you see one emerge, use that as your cue to take off! You can finish line at the shadow of the first support girdle.

Skyarrow Bridge is closed until you beat the Elite 4 in B/W 2.

Having a Pokemon with [Magma Armor](http://www.smogon.com/bw/abilities/magma_armor) or [Flame Body](http://www.smogon.com/bw/abilities/flame_body) will help speed up the rate at which your egg hatches. Multiple Pokemon with these abilities will not stack. I recommend Volcarona, because it can learn Fly.